# apt-get upgrade didn't update PHP but updated its php modules

Tags: upgrade, php, nginx

I performed

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and was expecting to see that PHP version update from 5.6.30 to 5.6.37. To my surprise, php version didn't upgrade but its modules did. I still see 5.6.30 in phpinfo

```
dpkg --list | grep php


ii  php5.6                           5.6.37-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    all          server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
ii  php5.6-bcmath                    5.6.37-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        Bcmath module for PHP
ii  php5.6-cli                       5.6.30-7+deb.sury.org~trusty+1                           amd64        command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
ii  php5.6-common                    5.6.30-7+deb.sury.org~trusty+1                           amd64        documentation, examples and common module for PHP
ii  php5.6-curl                      5.6.37-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        CURL module for PHP
ii  php5.6-fpm                       5.6.30-7+deb.sury.org~trusty+1                           amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
ii  php5.6-gd                        5.6.37-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        GD module for PHP
ii  php5.6-json                      5.6.37-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        JSON module for PHP
ii  php5.6-mbstring                  5.6.37-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        MBSTRING module for PHP
ii  php5.6-mysql                     5.6.37-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        MySQL module for PHP
ii  php5.6-opcache                   5.6.37-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        Zend OpCache module for PHP
ii  php5.6-readline                  5.6.37-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        readline module for PHP
ii  php5.6-xml                       5.6.37-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP
ii  php5.6-zip                       5.6.30-7+deb.sury.org~trusty+1                           amd64        Zip module for PHP
```

how to get the php version also upgraded to 5.6.37?

Output of apt-cache policy below:

```
sudo apt-cache policy php5.6-cli php5.6-common php5.6-fpm php5.6-zip
php5.6-cli:
  Installed: 5.6.30-7+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
  Candidate: 5.6.37-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
     5.6.37-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
 *** 5.6.30-7+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
php5.6-common:
  Installed: 5.6.30-7+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
  Candidate: 5.6.37-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
     5.6.37-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
 *** 5.6.30-7+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
php5.6-fpm:
  Installed: 5.6.30-7+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
  Candidate: 5.6.37-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
     5.6.37-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
 *** 5.6.30-7+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
php5.6-zip:
  Installed: 5.6.30-7+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
  Candidate: 5.6.37-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
     5.6.37-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
 *** 5.6.30-7+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: I haven't forced anything. just used "sudo apt-get upgrade" and it pick the packages to upgrade

Comment: Is there a way to now use the sury ppa? Thanks @N0rbert

Comment: Please edit the question to add the output of `apt-cache policy php5.6-cli php5.6-common php5.6-fpm php5.6-zip`.

Comment: @HarishChennamsetty I agree with fkraiem, please add output of `apt-cache policy php5.6-cli php5.6-common php5.6-fpm php5.6-zip` to the question. And please note, that installation from sury PPA does not lead to issues on my clean 14.04 LTS VM (see detailed result in my answer below).

Comment: I updated the output for apt-cache. Thank you.

Comment: Hmh, something looks strange there. It could be that somehow the name gviving of the packets could have changed. Here look, some are called trusty some of the packages are called ububtu 14 04, looks odd to me.
Installed: 5.6.30-7+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
Candidate: 5.6.37-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+
Could you please use https://pastebin.com/ and copy/paste what you got in /etc/apt/sources.list and all you got in subfolder /etc/apt/sources.d

Comment: @s1mmel please find the output here: https://pastebin.com/yvZn47yp
I didn't find /etc/apt/sources.d but I have sources.list.d
Thanks!

Comment: myabe that is the reason? 3. If you are using nginx, you are advise to add ppa:ondrej/nginx-mainline
   or ppa:ondrej/nginx

Comment: see https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/+index?batch=75&memo=75&start=75